# How to get value of multiple input field with different data-id in Array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have form that has multiple input field, using backbone I'm generating multiple input field with data-id. each time data-id will be different in sequence.

Now, I need to get value of all input field that user have created and filled.
(value will be populated on click event and user can create multiple input field.)

```
<div class="Title" data-id="title_1">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="Title" data-id="title_2">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="Title" data-id="title_3">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="Title" data-id="title_4">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="Title" data-id="title_5">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to get value with class and then using array.map, but I need value by data-id and so I can sync with the backbone collection

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give all the text box same classes so that you can access the user generated textboxes easily

Here is you HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div class="Title" data-id="title_1">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input class="textfield" type="text" value="val 1">
</div>

<div class="Title" data-id="title_2">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input class="textfield"  type="text" value="val 2">
</div>

<div class="Title" data-id="title_3">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input type="text" class="textfield" value="val 3">
</div>

<div class="Title" data-id="title_4">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input type="text" class="textfield" value="val 4">
</div>

<div class="Title" data-id="title_5">
  <label>Additional Title</label>
  <input type="text" class="textfield" value="val 5">
</div>
```

Here is your jquery

```
$( ".textfield" ).each(function( index ) {
  debugger;
  console.log( $(this).closest('div').attr('data-id'));
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).val() );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/L3xyL4oe/

```
//bind selector methods to easy to use functions
let $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
let $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

//setup function to quickly change dom list to an array
let toArray = (domList) => [].slice.call(domList);

//when button is clicked
$("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  //get all the inputs into an array
  let inputs = toArray($$(".Title[data-id^='title'] > input"));

  //iterate through the array
  for (let input of inputs) {
  //for each input with a value, alert the value
    if (input.value) alert(input.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote I'd appreciate a reason why. This does what was asked.